# SQL rows to Column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, rows, unpivot

I have a scenario where for a purchase i can be paid with either cash,card or voucher are all the above three. But i need a report to show the all the payment types in seperate lines but i captured all these value in a single row. the problem is how to transfer the rows values into columns .

For Ex.

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Order           Amount     Cash     Card    Voucher ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Purchase1       1000       500      300     200     ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

but i need the result has

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╗
║ Order           Amount  PayType  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╣
║ Purchase1        500     Cash    ║
║ Purchase1        300     Card    ║
║ Purchase1        200     Voucher ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Let can provide your suggestions to accomplish the above format.

Comment: Can you use php, java, or another language to edit the result set?

Comment: I need to do this through postgres sql query.

Comment: originally you have the data in wide format, but you want the data in narrow format. This is a well known problem and many languages such as R have implemented methods to do what you want. see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data). However I'm not sure whether SQL has methods to do this or if you need to loop through the cash card and voucher columns and use an insert statement.

Comment: This is generally called an unpivot.

Answer (score 1):

One way to unpivot your table

```sql
SELECT "Order", 
       CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN Cash
            WHEN n = 2 THEN Card 
            WHEN n = 3 THEN Voucher END Amount,
       CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN 'Cash' 
            WHEN n = 2 THEN 'Card'
            WHEN n = 3 THEN 'Voucher' END PayType      
  FROM table1 CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 3) n
```

Output:

| Order | amount | paytype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Purchase1 | 500 | Cash |
| Purchase1 | 300 | Card |
| Purchase1 | 200 | Voucher |

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d27a/2)** demo

Answer (score 1):

Using [unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) in PostgreSQL Array Functions

```
SELECT "Order",
        unnest(array[cash, card, voucher]) AS "amount",
        unnest(array['cash', 'card', 'voucher']) AS "PayType"
FROM bar
ORDER BY "PayType"
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e2e05/4)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT Order, Cash As Amount, 'Cash' As PayType
UNION ALL
SELECT Order, Card, 'Card'
UNION ALL
SELECT Order, Voucher, 'Voucher'
```

Comment: I knew it, but there will be any performance issues. can i get the result apart from union all.